# why is rawQuery() returning zero row?

Tags: android, sql, android-cursor, sqliteopenhelper

My Database has two tables.District and Place.I am running query on the Place table.

```
private void test(){
    Cursor cur = new DatabaseQuery().getPlaceDetailsForPhonebook(DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this).getMyWritableDatabase(),"hospital","District");
    Log.e("myapp","row = "+cur.getCount());
}
```

this is the getPlaceDetailsForPhonebook method

```
public Cursor getPlaceDetailsForPhonebook(SQLiteDatabase db,String type,String DIS_NAME){
    String sql;
    if (DIS_NAME.equals("District")) {
        sql = "SELECT name,phonenumber FROM Place WHERE type = '" + type + "'";
    }
    else {
        sql = "SELECT name,phonenumber FROM Place WHERE districtname = '"+DIS_NAME+"' AND type = '"+type+"'";
    }
    Log.e("myapp",sql);
    Cursor cr = null;
    try {
        cr = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        Log.e("myapp","inside method row = "+cr.getCount());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("myapp",e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return cr;

}
```

My DatabaseHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static SQLiteDatabase myWritableDb;
private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;

private DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context,"district.db",null,1);
}

public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}

public SQLiteDatabase getMyWritableDatabase() {
    if ((myWritableDb == null) || (!myWritableDb.isOpen())) {
        myWritableDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    return myWritableDb;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}}
```

All the query that are running on District table are returning correct results.I am using SqliteBrower and there i executed the same query(the query inside test() method) on Place table and it gave me correct result. So there is nothing wrong with the database.
My logcat

```
02-06 10:09:43.393 11938-11938/com.example.helpfinder E/myapp: SELECT name,phonenumber FROM Place WHERE type = 'hospital'
```

02-06 10:09:43.393 11938-11938/com.example.helpfinder E/myapp: inside method row = 0

02-06 10:09:43.393 11938-11938/com.example.helpfinder E/myapp: row = 0

Please help me.Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you get anything without the WHERE clause? And why is your `onCreate` empty?

Comment: @CL i solved my problem and posted the answer.Thanks for replying anyway. and onCreate is empty cause i don't need to add anything extra to it...

Answer (score 0):

well silly me.i just had to clear the previous db from my device and problem was solved straight away. i have to see if there is a way to delete it programmatically.